# Git - can not pull new changes - how to reset everything locally and force pulling current remote branch?

Tags: git, github

I tried `git reset --hard` and then `git pull` and getting error:

```
git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        .../components/../somefile.component.html
Please move or remove them before you merge.
Aborting
```

I do not remember ever touching this file..

How to really reset everything locally and just force pulling everything from remote?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset your local branch to the remote branch with

```
git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/branch-name
```

Answer (score 0):

some more options for you to delete untracked directories and files if no longer required, after that reset hard.

```
git clean -f -d && git reset --hard
```

Comment: Tried.. still showing same error as above.. Do you know any other way?

Comment: @Joe : With my command are you not able to delete untracked directories and files

Comment: @Joe : about  "git: 'credential-cache' is not a git command.", to this message  run "git config --global --unset credential.helper

Comment: I was but it did not prevent me from error stated in question.. I used the other answer and it worked for this case..